# WebLogic10.3 OutOfMemoryError

Tags: weblogic-10.x, out-of-memory

Weblogic 10.3  gives out of memory

Followings  thing I have done

1. Increased the -Xms512m
2. Increased the -Xmx1024m
3. Increased the max perm size in setdomainenv.bat

Is there any other way  to resolve this issue I have a 2 GB system?

It is a production machine and the size of the log is around 4 GB .When analysed the log I found many connection refused error

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to profile your application to find the memory leak. It could be open database connections or other resources not being handled properly

Just increasing the Xms and Xmx wont work beyond a point

Take a [Heap Dump into an HPROF file](http://visualvm.java.net/heapdump.html) and run this using Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool or [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)
or monitor this using [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html)